# Drag and Drop element linked with drawing line(path) width another element using SVG JS(ES6+)

Tags: javascript, svg, ecmascript-6

Good day guys. Please tell me how from the point of view of the organization of the code to implement drag and drop elements with drawing links between the dragged elements.

I partially managed to implement this, but I ran into a performance or focus loss issue (I guess).

After reading the [article](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/tutorials/svg/interactive/dragging/) and understanding the basics of drag and drop, I wanted to create links between the components, but there was a difficulty: when dragging an element and drawing a link line at the same time, as if the drag elements flew from the focus and fell (to the canvas).

**Here is the General logic:**

```js
let svg = document.querySelector('svg');

svg.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrag);
svg.addEventListener('mousemove', drag);
svg.addEventListener('mouseup', endDrag);
svg.addEventListener('mouseleave', endDrag);
    
let selectedElement = null;    
    
function startDrag(evt) {
  // select element evt.target
  // search all need lines communication with this element
}
function drag(evt) {
  // set coords selectedElement (x, y) by mouse position with offeset
  // set coords need LINES, BUT have problem (;,,,;)(\/ 
}
function endDrag(evt) {
   selectedElement = false;
   // clear temp map object line with 
}
```

I appreciate any help and think about how to compactly present what the problem is

I recorded a video but I only at that moment realized that I can't say anything without a translator https://youtu.be/y5cdIWu7_qQ .

I very much hope for your understanding me guys...

```js
// Перетаскивание элементов
(function () {
    let $document = $(document);

    const $svg = $('#main .canvas-svg'); // SVG

    // PC
    $document.on('mousedown', $svg, startDrag);
    $document.on('mousemove', $svg, drag);
    $document.on('mouseup', $svg, endDrag);
    $document.on('mouseleave', $svg, endDrag);

    // MOBILE
    $document.on('touchstart', $svg, startDrag);
    $document.on('touchmove', $svg, drag);
    $document.on('touchend', $svg, endDrag);
    $document.on('touchleave', $svg, endDrag);
    $document.on('touchcancel', $svg, endDrag);


    let selectedElement = false,
        offsetElement,
        transformElement;

    let selectDrawLineChanel = false; // текущая созданная (рисующая) линия при создании канал связи
    let mapMoveLineChanel = false; // список перемещаемых линий (связей) при перетаскивании блока


    function startDrag(e) {

        if (e.target.classList.contains('output-chanel')) { // при наведении на точку канала
            selectDrawLineChanel = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
            //initialiseDragging(e, selectDrawLineChanel);
            let outputChanel = e.target;
            let groupParent = e.target.closest('.draggable-group');
            let positionChanelOutput = getAbsolutePositionElement(outputChanel, outputChanel.cx.baseVal.value, outputChanel.cy.baseVal.value);


            console.log(groupParent);

            let attrsLine = {
                x1: positionChanelOutput.x,
                y1: positionChanelOutput.y,
                dataNameDeviceOutput: groupParent.getAttributeNS(null, 'data-name-device'),
                dataNameChanelOutput: outputChanel.getAttributeNS(null, 'data-name-chanel'),
                strokeWidth: 2,
                stroke: '#000',
                strokeLinecap : 'round',
            };

            setAttrElement(selectDrawLineChanel, attrsLine, null);

            let groupChanelLine = activeSVG.querySelector('.chanel-lines');
            groupChanelLine.appendChild(selectDrawLineChanel);

            console.log('startDrawLine');
        } else if (e.target.classList.contains('draggable')) { // при наведении на элемент
            selectedElement = e.target;
            initialiseDragging(e, selectedElement);
            console.log('startDragElement')
        } else if (e.target.parentNode.classList.contains('draggable-group')) { // при нажатии на устройство при перемещении
            selectedElement = e.target.parentNode;
            initialiseDragging(e, selectedElement);

            // поиск всех линий, относящахся к данному блоку при перемешении самого блока
            let nameDevice = selectedElement.getAttributeNS(null,'data-name-device'); // определяем имя девайса
            let groupChanelLines = activeSVG.querySelector('.chanel-lines');// ищем контейнер всех линий
            let selectMoveArrayLineChanel = groupChanelLines.querySelectorAll('[data-name-device-output],[data-name-device-input]'); // найти все линии с содержащие data-name-device-output | data-name-device-input внутри контейнера
            if (selectMoveArrayLineChanel.length) { // если нашел линии, то есть смысл дальше идти
                mapMoveLineChanel = new Map(); // объект мап line (lineChanel) - circle (chanelOutput | chanelInput)
                for (let i = 0; i < selectMoveArrayLineChanel.length; i++){ // перебираем линии
                    let itemLine = selectMoveArrayLineChanel[i]; // одна линия
                    if(itemLine.getAttributeNS(null, 'data-name-device-output') === nameDevice){ // поиск в output
                        let nameChanelOutput = itemLine.getAttributeNS(null, 'data-name-chanel-output'); // достаем из аттрибута линии название канала
                        let circleChanelOutput = selectedElement.querySelector(`.chanel-list-output [data-name-chanel="${nameChanelOutput}"]`); // находим окружность
                        mapMoveLineChanel.set(itemLine, circleChanelOutput);
                        console.log('add MAP output');
                    }else if(itemLine.getAttributeNS(null, 'data-name-device-input') === nameDevice){ // поиск в input
                        let nameChanelInput = itemLine.getAttributeNS(null, 'data-name-chanel-input'); // ищем порядковый номер канала
                        let circleChanelInput = selectedElement.querySelector(`.chanel-list-input [data-name-chanel="${nameChanelInput}"]`); // поиск окружности канала
                        mapMoveLineChanel.set(itemLine, circleChanelInput);
                        console.log('add MAP input');
                    }
                }
            }

            console.log('startDragElement');
        }
    }
    function drag(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(selectDrawLineChanel){ // рисуем линию за курсором мыши
            let coord = getMousePosition(e);
            setAttrElement(selectDrawLineChanel, {
                x2: coord.x,
                y2: coord.y
            });
            //console.log('drawLine: x =',coord.x, 'offsetElementX =', offsetElement.x, 'y =', coord.y, 'offsetElementY =', offsetElement.y);
        } else if (selectedElement) { // при перетаскивании элемента
            let coord = getMousePosition(e);
            transformElement.setTranslate(coord.x - offsetElement.x, coord.y - offsetElement.y); // переносим сам элемент


            /* PROBLEM HERE -----------------> */
            if(mapMoveLineChanel){ // перебираем все линии с их каналами относящиеся к перетаскиваему блоку
                mapMoveLineChanel.forEach((circle, line, map) => {
                    let coordsCircle = getAbsolutePositionElement(circle, circle.getAttributeNS(null, 'cx'), circle.getAttributeNS(null, 'cy'));

                    setAttrElement(line, { // init new coords for line by position circle-chanel
                        x1:coordsCircle.x,
                        y1:coordsCircle.y,
                    });

                    console.log(line, coordsCircle, mapMoveLineChanel);

                });
            }
            /* <----------------- PROBLEM HERE */
            
            console.log('drag');
        }
    }
    function endDrag(e) {
        if (selectDrawLineChanel) {
            console.log(e.target);
            if (e.target.classList.contains('input-chanel')) {
                let outputChanel = e.target;
                let groupParent = e.target.closest('.draggable-group');

                let cx = outputChanel.cx.baseVal.value;
                let cy = outputChanel.cy.baseVal.value;
                let cc = getAbsolutePositionElement(outputChanel, cx, cy);

                setAttrElement(selectDrawLineChanel, {
                    x2: cc.x,
                    y2: cc.y,
                    dataNameDeviceInput: groupParent.getAttributeNS(null, 'data-name-device'), // сохраняем имя девайса
                    dataNameChanelInput: e.target.getAttributeNS(null, 'data-name-chanel') // сохраняем порядковый номер (ид) канала в данном девайсе
                });

                selectDrawLineChanel = false;
                console.log('endDrawLine (ok)', cc.cx, cc.cy, e.target);
            } else {
                selectDrawLineChanel.remove();
                selectDrawLineChanel = false;
                console.log('endDrawLine (cancel)');
            }
        }
        if(selectedElement){
            selectedElement = false;
            console.log('mapMoveLineChanel =', mapMoveLineChanel);
            mapMoveLineChanel = false;
            console.log('endDragElement');
        }
    }


    function getAbsolutePositionElement(elem, x, y) {
        let svg = elem.ownerSVGElement;

        // Get the cx and cy coordinates
        let pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
        pt.x = x;
        pt.y = y;

        while (true) {
            // Get this elements transform
            let transform = elem.transform.baseVal.consolidate();
            // If it has a transform, then apply it to our point
            if (transform) {
                let matrix = elem.transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix;
                pt = pt.matrixTransform(matrix);
            }
            // If this element's parent is the root SVG element, then stop
            if (elem.parentNode === svg)
                break;
            // Otherwise step up to the parent element and repeat the process
            elem = elem.parentNode;
        }
        return pt;
    }



    function setAttrElement(element, attrs, namespace = null) {
        for (let attrName in attrs) {
            let snakeAttrName = attrName.replace(/([A-Z])/g, "-$1").toLowerCase();
            element.setAttributeNS(namespace, snakeAttrName, attrs[attrName]);
        }
        return element;
    }



    function convertCoords(element, x, y) {
        let offset = activeSVG.getBoundingClientRect();
        let matrix = element.getScreenCTM();

        return {
            x: (matrix.a * x) + (matrix.c * y) + matrix.e - offset.left,
            y: (matrix.b * x) + (matrix.d * y) + matrix.f - offset.top
        };
    }


    function getMousePosition(e) {
        let CTM = activeSVG.getScreenCTM(); // Возвращает DOMMatrix, представляющую матрицу, которая преобразует систему координат текущего элемента в систему координат окна просмотра SVG для фрагмента документа SVG.
        if (e.touches) { e = e.touches[0]; } // iPhone
        return {
            x: (e.clientX - CTM.e) / CTM.a,
            y: (e.clientY - CTM.f) / CTM.d
        }
    }

    // инициализация положения перетаскиваемого элемента (блока)
    function initialiseDragging(e, element) {
        offsetElement = getMousePosition(e);
        // Make sure the first transformElement on the element is a translate transformElement
        let transforms = element.transform.baseVal;
        if (transforms.length === 0 || transforms.getItem(0).type !== SVGTransform.SVG_TRANSFORM_TRANSLATE) {
            // Create an transformElement that translates by (0, 0)
            let translate = activeSVG.createSVGTransform();
            translate.setTranslate(0, 0);
            element.transform.baseVal.insertItemBefore(translate, 0);
        }
        // Get initial translation
        transformElement = transforms.getItem(0);
        offsetElement.x -= transformElement.matrix.e;
        offsetElement.y -= transformElement.matrix.f;
    }


})();
```

Comment: I may be wrong about this because I'm unable to see your code, I think you may need to add `pointer events:none` to the text.

Comment: I can add all the code, but I'm afraid it might be confusing. On if you comment out the line "PROBLEM HERE", it works without lag, but the lines are not drawn. I already assume that you need to simulate a separate stream. If I find a good solution, I give you the answer